# OleDbCommand, UPDATE

Tags: c#, oledb

With an Access table (CustomersTable) and two fields (CustomerID, CustomerName):

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE CustomersTable   SET CompanyName =  @p2   WHERE CompanyName =  @p1";
command.Parameters.Clear();
command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "xyz3";
command.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "xyz4";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

does not change the CompanyName field.

Comment: Ole Db Parameters are positional not named. At least with JET referring to `@p2` and `@p1` in that order will refer to the first parameter you add and then the second. IIRC JET has some quasi named parameter support where referring to `@p2`, `@p1`, `@p2` will refer to the first, second, and then first parameter (so although they're positional it's sort of like the first instance of each parameter name is used in determining position). TL;DR Don't use JET or ACE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OleDbCommand` doesn't support named parameters.

From [`OleDbCommand.Parameters` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   `OleDbCommand` when `CommandType` is set to `Text`. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the order in which `OleDbParameter` objects are added to the
>   `OleDbParameterCollection` **must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text**.

Actually, using `?` is not must but it is a comman.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and objects.

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE CustomersTable SET CompanyName = ? WHERE CompanyName = ?";
    command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "xyz3";
    command.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "xyz4";
    con.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```